# Real part of Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've this function

$$f(k,\theta) = \frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{\cot\delta_0(k) -i }$$

and i know that $k\cot\delta_0(k) = -\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{2}r_ek^2 + \cdots$
 it is an expansion.

How can i get that the $\Re{f(k,\theta)} = -a + a^2(a-\frac{1}{2}r_e)k^2$ ?

Comment: Are $k$ and $\delta_0$ complex also? If not you can just multiple by the conjugate top and bottom and you will have the result you desire (in part anyway)

Comment: @Chinny84 No, $k$ and $\delta_0$ are not complex. I know how to calculate the real part of a function but i don't know how to show that is $\Re{f(k,\theta)} = -a + a^2(a-\frac{1}{2}r_e)k^2$

Comment: You expand the denominator. $(1+x)^n = 1+nx + ...$ and keeping only $k^2$ terms and drop higher order terms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably already solved this by yourself, but to close off this question with an answer, I followed through on my comment.

$$
\Re f(k,\theta) = \frac{1}{k}\frac{\cot \delta_0(k)}{\cot^2 \delta_0(k) +1}
$$
multiplying top and bottom by $k^2$ we obtain
$$
\Re f(k,\theta) =\frac{k\cot \delta_0(k)}{k^2\cot^2 \delta_0(k) +k^2}
$$
using the expansion for $k\cot \delta_0(k) = -\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{2}r_ek^2$ the denominator becomes
$$
k^2\cot^2 \delta_0(k) +k^2 = \frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{1}{a}r_ek^2 + k^2 = \frac{1}{a^2} +\left(1 -\frac{r_e}{a}\right)k^2
$$
therefore
$$
\Re f(k,\theta) = \frac{-\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{2}r_ek^2}{\frac{1}{a^2} +\left(1 -\frac{r_e}{a}\right)k^2} = \frac{-a +\frac{a^2}{2}r_ek^2}{1 +a^2\left(1 -\frac{r_e}{a}\right)k^2}
$$
using
$$
\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x +...
$$
we obtain
$$
\Re f(k,\theta) = \left(-a +\frac{a^2}{2}r_ek^2\right)\left(1 - a^2\left(1 -\frac{r_e}{a}\right)k^2 + ..O(k^4)\right)\\
= -a +a^3\left(1 -\frac{r_e}{a}\right)k^2 + \frac{a^2}{2}r_ek^2\\
=-a + a^3k^2 -a^2r_ek^2 + \frac{a^2}{2}r_ek^2 = -a +a^3k^2 -\frac{a^2}{2}r_ek^2 
$$
This yields the result as required
$$
\Re f(k,\theta) = -a +a^2\left(a - \frac{r_e}{2}\right)k^2.
$$

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! :)